# Cannot set an array to be the value of another array in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C. I haven't been learning it for very long and one problem that I have encountered already is that I come across this error when trying to set the values inside of the ***new_src*** array:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
```

**My code is:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * add_0_to_front(char array[]){

  static char destination[10] = {'0'};
  strcat(destination, array);

  return destination;
}

int main(){

  char src[7] = "1111111";
  char new_src[8];

  *new_src = add_0_to_front(src);

  printf("%s\n", new_stack);

  return 0;
}
```

The purpose of the program is to place a '0' at the beginning of the src array. Essentially to make the binary value in *src* a length of 8.

Thanks.

Comment: And this needed to be tagged C# ...why?

Comment: [Yep, doesn't compile in C#](https://rextester.com/ALNV44641).

Comment: `*new_src` is the same as `new_src[0]` - do you understand now why your code doesn't work?

Comment: Get a good beginner's book. And don't tag all curly-brace languages whose names start with "C" - they are very different and you must know which one you're programming in.

Comment: I recommend reading this article so that you don't mis-tag your questions in future: [Understanding the Differences Between C#, C++, and C](https://csharp-station.com/understanding-the-differences-between-c-c-and-c)

Comment: C, C++ and C# are all distinct languages. Please only tag the language you are asking about.

Comment: Confirm the expected output is `01111111`

Comment: If you just want to place a `'0'` in the front why do you call `strcat()` ? Why not just `src[0] = '0'`?

Comment: Apparently OP wants to shift too, totally missed that.

Comment: `char src[7] = "1111111";` is incorrect since it does not leave room for the string terminator.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to use an array as a single object in C. The value of an array (that is, the entire sequence of values of its elements) cannot be assigned to another array or used in an expression. The reasons for this lie in the history of computers and the development of C.

When you do try to use an array in an expression, whether it is on the left side or the right side of an assignment, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, except when it is the operand of `sizeof`, is the operand of unary `&` or is a string literal used to initialize an array. C programmers are accustomed to this conversion and use arrays as pointers.

To accomplish your goal, a common solution is to design the routine to work on the array directly. Pass the array to the routine (by passing a pointer to its first element), and then write code in the routine to move all elements in the array back one position and store a `'0'` at the front.

Keep in mind you need to allow room in the array for a terminating null character if you will use it as a string with C library functions.

Another solution would be for the routine to use its own array and return a pointer to the first element of that array, and then the caller can copy data from the routine’s array to the caller’s array by using `memcpy`, as in `memcpy(new_src, add_0_to_front(src), sizeof new_src);`. One issue with that is managing the memory the routine uses for its own array. Using a `static` object inside the routine is bad form because it means only one result from the routine can be “live” at the same time; callers have to take care to be sure the data from the last call is no longer needed before the routine is called again. An alternative is to use `malloc` to allocate memory, but then the memory should be freed by calling `free` when it is no longer needed (unless it is no longer needed because the program is exiting now).

It is possible to embed an array in a `struct` and then use that as a single object. For example, `struct EightChar { char array[8]; };` declares a `struct EightChar` that contains an array of eight `char`, and that can be returned from a routine and assigned as an object.

Answer (score 1):

So, the exact cause of the error message is the line

```
*new_src = add_0_to_front(src); // char = char *
```

`add_0_to_front` is declared to return a value of type `char *`, but the expression `*new_src` is exactly equivalent to `new_src[0]`, which has type `char`.  You're trying to assign a `char *` value to a `char` object, which isn't allowed.

But there's a deeper problem here.

Arrays in C are weird, and are not treated like any other aggregate type.  You cannot use `=` to assign whole arrays; you can only assign to individual elements:

> **6.5.16 Assignment operators**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2 An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

where a modifiable lvalue is

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> 1 An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially
> designates an object;<sup>64)</sup> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the
> behavior is undefined. When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is
> specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A ***modifiable lvalue*** is an lvalue that
> **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
> recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>64) The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left
> operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
> object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
> as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.
> An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if `E` is a unary
> expression that is a pointer to an object, `*E` is an lvalue that designates the object to which `E` points.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

You can't return `destination` and assign it to `new_src` using the `=` operator.  What you *can* do is pass `new_src` as a parameter to `add_0_to_front` and modify it within the function.

But there's another problem - under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element<sup>1</sup>:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
> unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
> type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
> to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has
> `register` storage class, the behavior is undefined.

IOW, array expressions lose their "array-ness" when you pass them as arguments to a function.  Critically, pointers don't have any metadata that tell you whether they point to a single object or to the first element of an array, so there's no way to determine the array size based on the pointer itself - if you pass an array to a function, you must also pass its size as a separate parameter.

Here's one way of doing what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

/**
 * Add a 0 to the beginning of dst, then append the contents
 * of src to it.  
 */
void add_0_to_front( char *dst, size_t dst_size, const char *src )
{
  /**
   * Make sure dst isn't an invalid pointer *and* that there's
   * at least enough room to write the string "0" to it. 
   */
  assert( dst != NULL && dst_size >= 2 );

  strcpy( dst, "0" );
  strncat( dst, src, dst_size - 2 );
}

int main( void )
{
  /**
   * Array size is determined by the number of elements in the
   * initializer - in this case, the array size is 8 (7 characters
   * plus the string terminator)
   */
  char src[] = "1111111";

  /**
   * Array size is determined by taking the size of the src array (8)
   * and adding 1.
   */
  char dst[sizeof src + 1];

  add_0_to_front( dst, sizeof dst, src );
  printf( "src = %s, dst = %s\n", src, dst );

  return 0;
}
```

---

1. If you're interested in the historical reasons for this, check out [this paper](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) by Dennis Ritchie explaining the early development of C.

Answer (score -1):

You can try out below code. Return type of a add_0_to_front function is char* and need to collect back it in char* in main . In above code you are trying to collect it in new_src[0] or *new_src that is the reason you are getting warning or incorrect results

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>`enter code here`
    #include <string.h>

    char * add_0_to_front(char array[]){

    static char destination[10] = {'0'};
    strcat(destination, array);

    return destination;
    }

    int main(){

     char src[7] = "1111111";
     char* new_src = add_0_to_front(src);
     printf("%s\n", new_src);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This solution will not work. One issue is that add_0_to_front is not re-entrant since add_0_to_front relies on a static array which will get reused each time resulting in a failure if multiple users invoke add_0_to_front. The correct solution would be to malloc space within the add_0_to_front array, and to malloc the size based on the passed in array length +1.

Comment: The purpose for above program to put '0' at the beginning of the array as mentioned in the question. I am providing solution w.r.t current scenario. Here he is not concerned about multiple users or any other things for now.  For single user it will work and provides the output  "01111111"